# how do I write a ruby watir script for switching to a modal dialog(iframe) of a third party company(payment services)

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

How do I write a ruby watir script for switching to a modal dialog (iframe) of a third party company (payment services)? I always get element not found error message.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We expect that you've tried to solve this, that you show us your code, and you explain why it didn't work. Asking us to explain how to write a script when that documentation already exists is a waste of time and space. Please add what you've tried, explain how it failed, and we'll help you fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Given this HTML:

```
<frame id="foo">
  <a href="http://www.example.org">link</a>
</frame>
```

This snippet shows how to method-chain so that the element is found:

```
b.link(href: "http://www.example.org").exists?  
#=> false
b.frame(id: "foo").link(href: "http://www.example.org").exists?
#=> true
```

Answer (score 0):

If clicking on any element triggers a modal dialog (iframe) where you will have to enter texts in a textbox and click on Save button, then it will be like this-

```
@browser.iframe(index: 0).text_field(id: 'title').set 'Test Title'
@browser.iframe(index: 0).button(value: 'Save').click
```